# How to Page Through Facebook Graph API Friend List Results for More Than 19 Friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to page through all Facebook friend list results using the Graph API so I can get a count of all friends for a user (me, right now). I'm using the Graph API Explorer to test, but have also tried it with straight URL-based queries.

For example, I can start the process with a query like:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/me/friends?limit=5000&offset=0&access_token=MYTOKEN`

This gives me 19 results and a next page link. If I click/enter the next page link, it gives an empty data array (even though I have hundreds of friends).

When I play with `limit` and `offset`, they usually don't behave as expected. A working example is if I ask a `limit=10` and `offset=10`. If I do that, it will give me the second half of the original list.

But as soon as I increase `offset` above `19` I get an empty data array.

It's as if I only have 19 friends.

How can I get more than 19 friends from the Graph API?

Comment: You are aware that with API 2.0, your app is only able to see friends that are also users of the app, right …?

Comment: Right now I'm only using the Graph API Explorer. So what is this list, only FB users who are my friends who also use the Explorer?

Comment: and ok, if I switch to 1.0 and adjust offset I'm getting more results. Is 1.0 going away in favor of 2.0?

Comment: Of course. Have you not read the documentation about the changes that API 2.0 introduced …?

Comment: ok, i see the change now (FB app dev is all new to me today). so there's no way for me to retrieve my own list of friends via the Graph API without each of those friends explicitly granting me permission to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `context` fields seems to work here. It’s main purpose is to show you how many friends the current user and *another* user have in common – but if you query it *for* the current user (`/me`), it seems to show the count of all of the current user’s friends. (Makes sense, kinda – I have all of my friends “in common” with myself …)

```
/2.0/me?fields=context
```

will give you a structure of the following format,

```
{
  "context": {
    "mutual_friends": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "…",
          "name": "…"
        },
        {
          "id": "…",
          "name": "…"
        },
        …
      ],
      "paging": {
        "cursors": {
          "before": "…",
          "after": "…"
        }
      },
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 1234
      }
    },
```

The `total_count` under `summary` seems to be your total number of friends.

Answer (score 0):

Change the API version to 1.0 then you can query friend list successful.

```
/v1.0/me?fields=friends
```

Comment: yes, but it's deprecated and going away. further, no new Facebook apps are allowed to use v1.0 of the API.